# Check if entity contains record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a program where it adds courses to an entity table. I am creating the course as follows:

```
 var course = new CategoryToCourse
        {
          ContentItemID = contentItem.ContentItemID,
          IsRequiredCourse = contentItem.IsRequired,
          DueDate = dueDate,
          SortOrder = 0
        };
```

Now, before adding the course, I want to ceck if it already exists in the **CategoryToCourse** entity.

How I might approach that?

Comment: `if(!Context.CategoryToCourses.Any(x => x.ContentItemID == contentItem.ContentItemID))` would false if the properties don't match. It works with multiple properties as well. Just add ` &&...` for each property

Comment: You can always do 
`var data = context.CategoryToCourse.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ContentItemID == contentItem.ContentItemID);`
If(data == null) add
else don't

Answer (score 0):

Making some heavy assumptions here about how you define a duplicate, but your solution might look something like:

```
var existingCourse = dbContext.CategoryToCourses.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContentItemID == contentItem.ContentItemID);

if (existingCourse == null) 
{
   var course = new CategoryToCourse
      {
         ContentItemID = contentItem.ContentItemID,
         IsRequiredCourse = contentItem.IsRequired,
         DueDate = dueDate,
         SortOrder = 0
      };

   // save course to database via repository pattern or directly through your DbContext
}
```

Sidenote: in the future it'd be more beneficial to explain more about what you've tried and more details about your problem (eg in this case, is a "duplicate" a course with the same ContentItemID?)